# How can I build a d3.js linechart in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, charts, vuetify.js

I'm trying to understand how to build a line chart with d3.js library in a Vue.js project.

```
<template>
    <div ref="d3chart">
        <svg ref="chart" :width="width" :height="height" >
            <g transform="translate(50,50)">
                <g :transform="`translate(0,${svg_height})`" ref="XaxisContainer" />
                <g :transform="`translate(0,0)`" ref="YaxisContainer" />
                <g class="bars">
                    <rect v-for=" (d, index) in bars" :key="index" :x="d.x" :y="d.y" :height="d.height" :width="d.width"></rect>
                </g> 
            </g> 
        </svg>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';


export default {

props:{
    sensorId: Number,
},   

data(){
    return{
        g:null,
        svg: null,
        margin:200,
        width: 900,
        height: 800,
        svg_height: 600
    }
},
computed: {
    bars: function(){
       
        return this.dataset[this.sensorId].map(d => {
            return  {
                ...d,
                x: this.drawX(d),
                y: this.drawY(d),
                width:1,
                height: this.barHeight(d)
            }
        })
    },
    ...mapState(['dataset']),
    ...mapGetters({
        getData: 'getDataset'
    }),
    dataset: function (){
                //return this.$store.getters['getDataset'];
                return this.getData();
            },
},
mounted: function(){

    d3.select(this.$refs.XaxisContainer).call(d3.axisBottom(this.drawScale_x()).tickFormat(function (d) {
        return d+"Hz";
    }).ticks(30));


    d3.select(this.$refs.YaxisContainer)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(this.drawScale_y()).tickFormat(function (d) {
                return d+"g";
            }).ticks(20));

},
methods:{
        drawScale_x: function(){
                return d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0,50]).nice()
                    .range([0,this.width - this.margin]);
        },
        drawScale_y: function(){
                return d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0,500]).nice()
                    .range([this.height - this.margin,0]);
        },
        scale_x: function(temp){
                var scale_x =  d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0,50]).nice()
                    .range([0,this.width - this.margin]);
                    return (scale_x(temp));
        },
        scale_y: function(temp){ 
                var scale_y = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0,500]).nice()
                    .range([this.height - this.margin,0]);
                return scale_y(temp)
        },
        drawX: function(d) { return this.scale_x(d.x); },
        drawY: function(d) { return this.scale_y(d.y); },
        barHeight: function(d) { return this.svg_height - this.scale_y(d.y); }
},
watch:{
    dataset: {        
        handler: function(){
        return this.dataset[this.sensorId].map(d => {
            return  {
                ...d,
                x: this.drawX(d),
                y: this.drawY(d),
                width:1,
                height: this.barHeight(d)
            }
        })
        },
        deep:true,
        
    }
}
}
</script>

<style>

    .bar {
        fill: steelblue;
    }
    .selectedbar {
        fill: orangered;
    }

</style>
```

First of all I've tried to build a bar chart and that works and it's also real time updated. However i don't understand how to draw a line instead of bars. I also tried to do a init() method and to put everything inside that method but the problem is that if I want a real time updated chart i need to split functions so that methods can be called up individually to update the chart.

**That's the chart now:**
[image: Chart Now]

**That's what i would like to have:**
[image: New Chart]

**That's the barchart I used as skeleton:**
[image: Bar Chart Skeleton]

EDIT: I created a computed property to watch the state of the dataset array stored in Vuex. Then i set a watcher on the computed property but the chart is not updating. What can i do?
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Seems to be you have more than one question here. Please focus on a specific one and clarify the problem you need to solve.

Comment: The problem is how to structure a d3.js line chart in vue.js. I tried to use the skeleton of the bar chart but I'm stuck because i don't know how to draw lines instead of bars. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you get vs the desired picture (you can do it in Paint or similar tool) to help us understand your needs

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I updated the post with required information. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Your problem is not how to draw a line with d3 in Vue. It's how to draw a line with d3. Period. Point 9 in [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/gordlea/27370d1eea8464b04538e6d8ced39e89) is your answer. In your component, replace the `.bars` iteration with the path element of your line. [docs here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-line). [search engine here](https://www.google.com/). Also please read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and its accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of **Vue.js** & **D3.js** linechart

```js
const data = [40,45,47,59,54,53,62,69,76,85,94,111,129,144,154,157,161,155,164,174];

const buildChart = ref => {
    const svg = d3.select(ref);
  const xScale = 
    d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 50])
    .range([0, 300]);
                  
 const xAxis = 
        d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale);

svg.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50,210)')
  .call(xAxis);                 

const yScale = 
    d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([200, 0])
    .range([0, 200]);
                  
 const yAxis = 
        d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale);

svg.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50,10)')
  .call(yAxis);         
    
const path = data.reduce((p, v, i) => {
 const x = 300 / data.length * i;
 const y = yScale(v);
 if (i === 0) return `M ${x},${y}`;
 return p + ` L ${x},${y}`;
}, null)

svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50, 10)')
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', path)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'red')
  .style('stroke-width', 2)
}


Vue.component('d3-component', {
  mounted() {
    buildChart(this.$refs.svg)
  },
  template: '<svg ref="svg" width="400" height="250"></svg>'
})

new Vue({ el: '#d3-component-demo' })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="d3-component-demo">
  <d3-component/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The chart works! How can I do to map negative values on y axes? Is there a way to put the cart in a viewbox to make it responsive? If I want to smooth line what can i do? I need to draw a sinusoidal function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set negative values to X axis with domain:

   const xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-50, 50])
2. I (personally) prefer not to use viewbox. Instead, I pass the width and height attributes explicitly to SVG and use them in the chart calculations
3. You can round by **stroke-linejoin='round'**, but it does not work smoothly in every case

```js
const data = [40,45,47,59,54,53,62,69,76,85,94,111,129,144,154,157,161,155,164,174];

const buildChart = ref => {
    const svg = d3.select(ref);
  const xScale = 
    d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-50, 50])
    .range([0, 300]);
                  
 const xAxis = 
        d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale);

svg.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50,210)')
  .call(xAxis);                 

const yScale = 
    d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([200, 0])
    .range([0, 200]);
                  
 const yAxis = 
        d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale);

svg.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50,10)')
  .call(yAxis);         
    
const path = data.reduce((p, v, i) => {
 const x = 300 / data.length * i;
 const y = yScale(v);
 if (i === 0) return `M ${x},${y}`;
 return p + ` L ${x},${y}`;
}, null)

svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50, 10)')
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', path)
  .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'red')
  .style('stroke-width', 5)
}


Vue.component('d3-component', {
  mounted() {
    buildChart(this.$refs.svg)
  },
  template: '<svg ref="svg" width="400" height="250"></svg>'
})

new Vue({ el: '#d3-component-demo' })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="d3-component-demo">
  <d3-component/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Probably i solved the issue. I used curve() to create a curve instead of a line and then I added negative values to domain. I stil have a problem: the chart is not responsive if i try to resize the window. What can i do?